# how to store data and retrieve it using network connection in android

Tags: android, storage, android-networking, android-database

Sorry if this question sound foolish .I am new to android and I am studying data storage option in android . My question is how to store data on cloud or server and retrieve it when i want.

If it is possible . I to want study and practice it. Is there any option to do practice like free cloud space or server space on which i can store my data and retrieve it for practise.

Data can be image,text,structured data etc.

Please guide me . I have completed topics sharedPreference,InternalStorage,ExternalStorage and Sqlite. And right now looking for storing data on cloud or server

Comment: check out Firebase from google : https://firebase.google.com

Answer (score 0):

```
Url url=new Url("server address");
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000);   
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true); 
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);  
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");    　　
        httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);               

        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can practice with Google Drive for example. There is Google Drive [API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/). Upload some files and implement API module in your application. 
There is a very good library for android that let you write very nice API module. Check [this](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) .

Answer (score 0):

Check for firebase. You  van set it  up by selecting  an option in android  studio. This is the Best for the start.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data on server then you will required backend programming for connectivity with Android.. you can prefer this tutorial.. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/